# Jquery form validation and submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have the following code to validate and send the form.
Unfortunately, the validation working well, but the page reloads not anymore, just loads the `contact.php.`
I'm new in coding, could you help me, what I did wrong?

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
  $('#orderForm').validate({

  });


  $.ajax({
     url:'contact.php',
     type:'post',
     data:{fname:fname,lname:lname,email:email},
     success:function(response){
        location.reload(); // reloading page
  
     }
  });

});
});
```

HTML

```
 <form id="orderForm" name="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
            <h1>kapcsolat</h1>
            
            
              <label for="first_name">Vezetéknév</label>
              <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>
              
              <label for="last_name">Keresztnév</label>
              <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
              
              <label for="email">E-mail cím</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
              
              <label for="number">Telefonszám</label>
              <input type="number" name="phone">
              
              <label for="message">Megjegyzés</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
              
              <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"> Küldés</button>



          </form>
```

Thank your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the user back the MAIN INDEX page, instead reload the same page again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
  
      $('#orderForm').validate({
    
      });


      $.ajax({
         url:'contact.php',
         type:'post',
         data:{fname:fname,lname:lname,email:email},
         success:function(response){
            alert("Thank you, we will get back to you shortly.");
            // **** redirect back to Main Index Page *****
            window.location.href = "YourMainIndexPage.php";
         }
      });
    
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, the result is the same. It works only if I take out the  **$('#orderForm').validate({ });** section. But why?

Comment: this is my PHP code... `<?php     $message_sent = false;     if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {             $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];             $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];             $email = $_POST['email'];             $message = $_POST['message'];                $mailTo = "test@test.com";             $headers = "From: My website".$first_name;             $txt = "Hello".$first_name.".\n\n".$message;                  mail($mailTo, $headers, $txt, $first_name, $last_name );             $message_sent = true;         } ?>`